# How to fix the update problem in concurrent request in ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an ASP.NET Web API 2 project with .NET Framework 4.6.2. When I send two concurrent requests to a specific endpoint from Postman, only one record is updated in the database.

Here is the code I'm having the issue:

```
private HttpResponseMessage CallGameNew(RequestDto requestDto)
{
    // Code omitted for brevity.
    
    List<GameBank> gameBankResult = null;

    //Query GameBank database
    gameBankResult = _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.GetGames(g =>
        g.productCode == requestDto.productCode && g.referenceId == Guid.Empty);

    if (gameBankResult != null && gameBankResult.Count() >= requestDto.quantity)
    {
        var k = requestDto.quantity - 1;
        for (var i = k; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            gameBankResult[i].clientTrxRef = gameRequest.clientTrxRef;
            gameBankResult[i].referenceId = gameRequest.referenceId;
            gameBankResult[i].requestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            gameBankResult[i].responseDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        //***** UPDATE GameBank *****
        _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.Update(gameBankResult[k]);

        if (requestDto.quantity == 1)
        {
            //Code omitted for brevity.
        }
            
    }

    _unitOfWork.Save();

    return response;
}
```

I tried **DbUpdateConcurrencyException** handling in my code above. This seems working for only 2 concurrent requests, but if there are more than 2 concurrent requests I am having the same issue.

```
//Update GameBank
try
{
    _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.Update(gameBankResult[k]);
    _unitOfWork.Save();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
{
    // Refresh and retry
    gameBankResult[k] = _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.GetByID(gameBankResult[k].GameBankID);
    _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.Update(gameBankResult[k]);
    _unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

I tried using a **transaction**. But when I tried a performance test in Postman, 150 requests were sent (3 virtual users for 1 minute with a fixed load profile). Only 134 records were updated in the table. I got deadlocks.

```
private HttpResponseMessage CallGameNew(RequestDto requestDto)
{
    // Code omitted for brevity.
    
    List<GameBank> gameBankResult = null;

    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
        new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
    {
        //Query GameBank database
        gameBankResult = _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.GetGames(g =>
            g.productCode == requestDto.productCode && g.referenceId == Guid.Empty);

        if (gameBankResult != null && gameBankResult.Count() >= requestDto.quantity)
        {
            var k = requestDto.quantity - 1;
            for (var i = k; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                gameBankResult[i].clientTrxRef = gameRequest.clientTrxRef;
                gameBankResult[i].referenceId = gameRequest.referenceId;
                gameBankResult[i].requestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                gameBankResult[i].responseDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            }

            //***** UPDATE GameBank *****
            _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.Update(gameBankResult[k]);

            if (requestDto.quantity == 1)
            {
                //Code omitted for brevity.
            }
                
        }

        _unitOfWork.Save();
        scope.Complete();
    }

    return response;
}
```

So I removed the transaction and added **WebApiThrottle** to force requests every second.

Here is the service:

```
private HttpResponseMessage CallGameNew(RequestDto requestDto)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    //ProductCode Conversion
    var productCode =
        _unitOfWork.ProductCodeRepository.GetByCode(p => p.clientCode == requestDto.productCode);

    if (productCode != null)
    {
        requestDto.productCode = productCode.gameCode;
    }

    var gameRequest = _mapper.Map<RequestDto, GameRequest>(requestDto);

    //Unique reference ID
    gameRequest.referenceId = Guid.NewGuid();

    var gameRequestDto = _mapper.Map<GameRequest, GameRequestDto>(gameRequest);
    //Create signature
    gameRequest = UtilitiesWatson.CreateSignature(gameRequestDto, RequestType.Initiate);

    //Set service
    gameRequest.service = "OUR";
    gameRequest.customerID = 5; //WATSON
    gameRequest.clientTrxRef = requestDto.clientTrxRef; //WATSON

    //Add initiation request into database
    _unitOfWork.GameRepository.Insert(gameRequest);
    _unitOfWork.Save();

    GameBank gameBankResult = null;

    gameBankResult = _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.GetGame(g =>
        g.productCode == requestDto.productCode && g.referenceId == Guid.Empty);
    _unitOfWork.Save();

    if (gameBankResult != null)
    {
        gameBankResult.clientTrxRef = gameRequest.clientTrxRef;
        gameBankResult.referenceId = gameRequest.referenceId;
        gameBankResult.requestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        gameBankResult.responseDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.Update(gameBankResult);
        _unitOfWork.Save();

        var gameBankConfirmResponse =
            _mapper.Map<GameBank, GameConfirmResponse>(gameBankResult);

        gameBankConfirmResponse.purchaseStatusDate = DateTime.Now;
        gameBankConfirmResponse.clientTrxRef = gameRequest.clientTrxRef;

        //ProductCode Conversion
        var productCodeReverse = _unitOfWork.ProductCodeRepository.GetByCode(p =>
            p.gameCode == requestDto.productCode);

        if (productCodeReverse != null)
        {
            gameBankConfirmResponse.productCode = productCodeReverse.clientCode;
        }

        var resultResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gameBankConfirmResponse,
            Formatting.Indented,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            });
        response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(resultResponse, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"),
        };
        //Set service
        gameBankConfirmResponse.service = "OUR";
        gameBankConfirmResponse.clientTrxRef = requestDto.clientTrxRef;

        _unitOfWork.GameConfirmResponseRepository.Insert(gameBankConfirmResponse);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Here is the WebApiThrottle in WebApiConfig:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ThrottlingHandler()
{
    Policy = new ThrottlePolicy(perSecond: 2, perMinute: 28)
    {
        IpThrottling = true,
        EndpointThrottling = true,
        EndpointRules = new Dictionary<string, RateLimits>
        {
            { "api/v2/game/watson/purchase", new RateLimits { PerSecond = 1, PerMinute = 22, PerHour = 1100 } }
        }
    },
    Repository = new CacheRepository(),
    QuotaExceededMessage = "You may only perform this action every {0} seconds."
});
```

What are your suggestions? (My goal is to handle multiple concurrent requests that's why I am trying to find a proper way.)

Here is the final working code:

```
private HttpResponseMessage CallGameNew(RequestDto requestDto)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    //ProductCode Conversion
    var productCode =
        _unitOfWork.ProductCodeRepository.GetByCode(p => p.clientCode == requestDto.productCode);

    if (productCode != null)
    {
        requestDto.productCode = productCode.gameCode;
    }

    var gameRequest = _mapper.Map<RequestDto, GameRequest>(requestDto);

    //Unique reference ID
    gameRequest.referenceId = Guid.NewGuid();

    var gameRequestDto = _mapper.Map<GameRequest, GameRequestDto>(gameRequest);
    //Create signature
    gameRequest = UtilitiesWatson.CreateSignature(gameRequestDto, RequestType.Initiate);

    //Set service
    gameRequest.service = "OUR";
    gameRequest.customerID = 5; //WATSON
    gameRequest.clientTrxRef = requestDto.clientTrxRef; //WATSON

    //Add initiation request into database
    _unitOfWork.GameRepository.Insert(gameRequest);
    _unitOfWork.Save();

    GameBank gameBankResult = null;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            gameBankResult = _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.GetGame(g =>
                g.productCode == requestDto.productCode && g.referenceId == Guid.Empty);
            _unitOfWork.Save();

            if (gameBankResult != null)
            {
                gameBankResult.clientTrxRef = gameRequest.clientTrxRef;
                gameBankResult.referenceId = gameRequest.referenceId;
                gameBankResult.requestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                gameBankResult.responseDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.Update(gameBankResult);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                break;  //exit from while loop
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            _unitOfWork.ClearChangeTracker(); //IS REQUIRED, so the next select will read new RowVersion also
            Thread.Sleep((new Random()).Next(0, 1000)); //if you want to add a random pause 0-1 second
        }
    }

    var gameBankConfirmResponse =
            _mapper.Map<GameBank, GameConfirmResponse>(gameBankResult);

    gameBankConfirmResponse.purchaseStatusDate = DateTime.Now;
    gameBankConfirmResponse.clientTrxRef = gameRequest.clientTrxRef;

    //ProductCode Conversion
    var productCodeReverse = _unitOfWork.ProductCodeRepository.GetByCode(p =>
        p.gameCode == requestDto.productCode);

    if (productCodeReverse != null)
    {
        gameBankConfirmResponse.productCode = productCodeReverse.clientCode;
    }

    var resultResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gameBankConfirmResponse,
        Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });
    response = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StringContent(resultResponse, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json"),
    };
    //Set service
    gameBankConfirmResponse.service = "OUR";
    gameBankConfirmResponse.clientTrxRef = requestDto.clientTrxRef;

    _unitOfWork.GameConfirmResponseRepository.Insert(gameBankConfirmResponse);
    _unitOfWork.Save();

    return response;
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be two, there should be an exception. `with the same parameters` means you're trying to overwrite the same object you just loaded from two different requests. That's the very definition of an optimistic concurrency conflict. This isn't just a database issue either. If you tried something similar with AWS S3 or any API that uses ETags you'd get a similar error.

Comment: Do you mean catching concurrency exceptions and getting a new ID and then updating is OK like in my sample solution?

Comment: You should enclose your **try...catch** inside a "while" cycle, to handle any number of requests. Your example works until there are two requests only (no more). The first request is updating inside "try"; in the same time, the second is updating inside "catch"... and what would happen on the third request? So you should "save" inside "try" only; and in case of exception, find again a Guid.Empy inside "catch" and restart again (**try**ing again to save, going up to "try" code).

Comment: In this way, for the system to correctly handle Optimistic Concurrency, you need to define a RowVersion (or Guid) column with a ConcurrencyToken and DatabaseGenerated... Computed annotations, or equivalent api fluent commands also...

Comment: I tried my solution up to 5 concurrent requests with Postman, it worked.

Comment: Yes, it's your code: you can do how you like, but think: any exception inside **try** block will be handled by the **catch** block. But you put some update and save instructions **inside catch block also**. And, what about any eventual (concurrency) exception verifying inside the **catch** block?

Comment: @FabioCaruso you are right, how about my updated code?

Comment: "how about this code?" is not on-topic on Stack Overflow. If you still have a problem, please explain it. If it solved your issue, post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am still having issues. I will explain it asap.

Comment: @GertArnold I have updated my explanation and revised the code.

Comment: You rewrite your code using Pessimistic Concurrency: to lock a group of rows, READ COMMITTED cannot be enough. Use SERIALIZABLE isolation instead. See that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: But at the end, reanalyzing the problem: if with 150 concurrent requests you don't have exceptions anymore, all is ok, because all the requests have been completed without errors.

Comment: Can I somehow delay concurrent requests in the filter attribute or elsewhere? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @FabioCaruso optimistic concurrency isn't broken. In fact it's always been the basic concurrency strategy in .NET and **increases** throughput by several orders of magnitude. Increasing locks may cover up the original problem but *easily* result in bigger ones, like deadlocks or an application that crawls to a halt

Comment: @Cenk the updated code is broken - TransactionScope uses an explicit database transaction that forces a connection to remain open for a long time. It's clear the non-repository classes you use are breaking EF Core's behavior. I'd suggest *removing* them completely, and just using EF Core itself, as intended. To understand how optimistic concurrency works or how conflicts occur, read the docs: [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations)

Comment: @Cenk the updated code is broken - TransactionScope uses an explicit database transaction that forces a connection to remain open for a long time. It's clear the non-repository classes you use are breaking EF Core's behavior. I'd suggest *removing* them completely, and just using EF Core itself, as intended. To understand how optimistic concurrency works or how conflicts occur, read the docs: [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used WebApiThrottle to force clients to send requests every 1 second and this seems to solve my problem. What is your opinion?

Comment: OK, I will rewrite the question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you are right: when I started to comment this question, I exposed the fact that Optimistic Concurrency had to be used, using try...catch blocks. We all know it's faster and better in most cases. I didn't like when Cenk went back to blocks with transactions, eliminating "try"... But we must also consider also that, in this case, RowVersion column (timestamp or guid) should be implemented (with Concurrency token annotations or better with Api fluent), so system can add it in the sql where clause.

Comment: It wouldn't seem that complicated: each row is updated only once by a single request...

Comment: I've never had a problem like this before, If you have experience on this subject, can you guide me? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Re-applying Optimistic Concurrency (no transactions), adding a try-catch block for DbUpdateConcurrencyException, and adding rowversion to the entity, will it ease my pain? @FabioCaruso I want to fix my issue and handle concurrent requests at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your Update method works (hoping it updates the relative entities), and I understand that it's more difficult to change the whole structure of your program to eliminate the "repository coding", and use the DbContext instance like "Unit of Work", naturally doing operations inside an "using" block. Nevertheless, if you have the patience to add, in your table, a column like this (assuming you are using SQL Server), you can implement the Optimistic Concurrency:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
[ConcurrencyCheck]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

And you can try to use this piece of code I wrote in 10 minutes, so we can only hope it solves your problem:

```
private HttpResponseMessage CallGameNew(RequestDto requestDto)
{
    // Code omitted for brevity.

    List<GameBank> gameBankResult = null;
    
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {           
            //Query GameBank database
            gameBankResult = _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.GetGames(g => g.productCode == requestDto.productCode && g.referenceId == Guid.Empty);

            if (gameBankResult != null && gameBankResult.Count() >= requestDto.quantity)
            {
                var k = requestDto.quantity;
                for (var i = 0; i < k; i++)
                {
                    gameBankResult[i].clientTrxRef = gameRequest.clientTrxRef;
                    gameBankResult[i].referenceId = gameRequest.referenceId;
                    gameBankResult[i].requestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    gameBankResult[i].responseDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.Update(gameBankResult[i]);
                }
            
                if (requestDto.quantity == 1)
                {
                    //Code omitted for brevity.
                }            

                _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.Save();
                break;  //exit from while loop
            }           
        }
        catch
        {
            _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();  //IS REQUIRED, so the next select will read new RowVersion also
            Thread.Sleep((new Random()).Next(0, 1000));  //if you want to add a random pause 0-1 second
        }           
    }

    return response;
}
```

Be patient to change the line:

```
_dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

according to your dbcontext class name.

Good luck.

Comment: I will try and let you know, thank you for your help. Does this code support multiple concurrent requests?

Comment: I mean if 2 concurrent requests come to this endpoint, does your code update 2 records in the database?

Comment: Yes, be sure. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I examined your sample carefully, I don't have ´dbcontext´ in the service layer. I think I should add ´_dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();´ in the unit of work right?

Comment: I am getting ChangeTracker does not contain a definition for Clear :(

Comment: See that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-7.0  You are using a previous version of EntityFramework Core...

Comment: I changed it like this `public void ClearChangeTracker() { foreach (var entry in _context.ChangeTracker.Entries()) { entry.State = EntityState.Detached; } }` and seems no problem. Does it affect other operations?

Comment: I wonder if using `ClearChangeTracker` the way I posted in my previous comment, can cause a side effect?

Comment: You can use your ClearChangeTracker method, because the effect is the same: from the catch block, the code flow will go up to "Query GameBank database", reading a new value of RowVersion column, and trying again to update your rows.

Comment: Please check my edited final working code in my post.

Comment: I wonder if querying and then updating the same database in two separate applications at the same time, can cause side effects? One of them has this updated code and the other has the older one. This one is a legacy web API and the other one is an asp.net core web API.

Comment: I seem to understand that in the "final working code", using Optimistic Concurrency, you save only one row at a time, so if another EF Core app works on the same database, you didn't have any problem (but the EF Core app to work right, must use a a similar technique). For an older web API, consider that Microsoft SQL Server transaction isolation default level is READ COMMITTED, so if you didn't changed it in your database, the row will be locked before being written (Pessimistic Concurrency). This ensures compatibility, at the expense of speed.

Comment: Instead in the best case scenario, in which everyone uses Optimistic Concurrency, READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT isolation level could be enabled on the database, to have max speed...

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, you said the default level is READ COMMITTED. But if it is default, how to READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT level be enabled?

Comment: From an SQL command line, you should digit (for one time only) the command: `ALTER DATABASE "YourDatabaseName" SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;`   after that, to enable read committed snapshot isolation, you should digit: `ALTER DATABASE "YourDatabaseName" SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;`  ensuring that there isn't any other connection active, because all active transitions will be rolled back.

Comment: When I added similar changes to the ASP.NET Core API and started a performance test with JMeter. I got this error from the ASP.NET Core API: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.`

Comment: I don't know the reason for this behavior, with JMeter. If you want, you can disable it again, typing: `ALTER DATABASE "YourDatabaseName" SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF;` so READ COMMITTED will be restored. You can verify the current state of isolation, at any time, typing: `DBCC USEROPTIONS;`

Comment: I just changed the code, NOT altered the database.

Comment: Should I alter the database?

Comment: We should suppose that you are the ADMIN or the OWNER of the database, to issue ALTER DATABASE command. First, typing `DBCC USEROPTIONS;` you can see your actual isolation level. After, you can execute those two lines of commands. They are permanent. You must use `ALTER DATABASE "DatabaseName" SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF;` to return to READ COMMITTED level. Try to LocalDb first, to be sure with this operation.

Comment: Actually without altering the database, adding the nearly same code to the new API solved my problem. I did 10 threads with JMeter, and worked as it expected without concurrency problems. Thank you for your time and patience.